# FFMPEG : Add a fixed size image on a video, regardless of the video width & height (resolution)

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, resolution

This is my code that adds an image to videos, running via PHP:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10"  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4');
```

It works well but the problem is, the image is scaled down or up, up on the video resolution. For example in the following images the logo width is `50px` but videos resolution are different:

[image]

and this one

[image]

**How can I prevent the image from scaling down/up ?**

---

## Update

Thanks to [Mulvya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/mulvya), he proposed these codes

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 
"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(W/H)*ih/8:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10"
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 
"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(W/H)*ih/8:ih/8[wm][base];[wm]setsar=1[wmsar];
[base][wmsar]overlay=10:10"
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

that works very well, but it doesn't keep the logo aspect ratio.
I tried this code on two videos with different resolution and this is the result

[image]

and this one

[image]

Is it possible to improve this solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the scale2ref filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 
"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(W/H)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10"
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This will resize the logo's height to 1/8th of the height of the video.

You have to replace `W/H` with the values for the image e.g. if the PNG is 320x270, then it should be `scale2ref=(320/270)*ih/8:ih/8`

Comment: Thank you very much. I **updated** the question, there is a very little problem with your solution

Comment: What's your logo resolution?

Comment: for testing, it is 505X384.

Comment: but after designing the new logo, I will replace the dimensions

Comment: Added a filter to reset aspect.

Comment: I tried the new code, it didn't change anything. the same result generated

Comment: Looks like anamorphic videos are the issue. Check now.

Comment: Can I do the same thing for blurring a section (a rectangle) of video? because by giving width/height to blur filter, the above problem persists

Comment: Code not working for me. Any other solution using ffmpeg?

Comment: @Farzad What do you mean by, "not working"? You should provide a link to a pastebin showing your actual command and the complete console output.

Comment: Post a new Q with what LN asked for.

Comment: @Mulvya, where is the doc for this command that has that level of detail where one could construct other filters as complex and effective as the one you used in this answer?

Comment: I believe that first `ih` is `iw` according to my calculations

Comment: No. We wish to apply the aspect ratio of the image. W/H does that. iw would distort since it introduces the reference's aspect ratio which is irrelevant to the image's proportions.

Comment: I am using this url and getting unfortunately what is problem here ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I am looking for since last month. <3

Comment: @Youans looks like that according to my outputs